# In VIM, replace path with slashes without using escape slashes

Tags: vim, regular-expression, vi

In vim I want to substitute a long path `/a/b/f/g/d/g` with another `/s/g/w/d/g/r` in a text file. Usually I use `\/` but there are too many slashes here. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use another character instead of slash `/` as delimiter to substitution command.

Example using `#`:

```
:%s#/a/b/f/g/d/g#/s/g/w/d/g/r#
```

Comment: Very nice, this is the best solution so far.

Comment: This also works in ed, sed, perl, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use sed

> #### Example 1 – sed `@` delimiter: Substitute `/opt/omni/lbin` to `/opt/tools/bin`
>
> When you substitute a path name which has `/`, you can use `@` as a delimiter instead of `/`. In the sed example below, in the last line of the input file, `/opt/omni/lbin` was changed to `/opt/tools/bin`.
>
> ```
> $ sed 's@/opt/omni/lbin@/opt/tools/bin@g' path.txt /usr/kbos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/jbin/:/usr/bin:/usr/sas/bin /usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin/:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/omni/bin: /opt/tools/bin:/opt/omni/sbin:/root/bin
> ```

From: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/unix-sed-tutorial-advanced-sed-substitution-examples/